# How to Setup Geokit with Google geocoder: client_id and cryptographic_key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, geokit

I have been trying at for a couple hours to get geocoder to work with google. I more or less am trying to figure out how to configure my google account and the code below to make geocoder work

```
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.client_id = ''
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.cryptographic_key = ''
```

For the various parameters I have tried, I get the following response back from google.

```
Unable to authenticate the request. Provided 'signature' is not valid for the provided
client ID. Learn more:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth
```

On the Google Developer panel, there are the following options:
1. By default Client ID and Email Address fields are given for the Compute Engine and App Engine. I have the following APIs enabled: BigQuery, Geocoding, Google Cloud SQL, Google Cloud Storage, Google Storage JSON API, Google Maps API v3, Google Maps Coordinate API, Google Maps Geolocation API

When you click to create a new client ID, you are given three options: web application, service account, and installed application. I have tried web application and installed application which both give a field called "Client Secret" which I input to the variable "cryptographic_key". It also gives a client ID which I used in the "client_id" field. The last option, service, downloads a certificate which has a private key inside. I did not know what to do with it and couldn't extract the private key.

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:
Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.api_key = 'myApiKey'

This is the key you use for the free service, if you are using the paid "Maps API for Business" then those 2 parameters are correct.

This is in the current README. Possibly the documentation doesn't make this clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

That pretty much sums up what you'll need and where to get it.